# Using square of explanatory variables when the correlation is high

Tags: regression, multicollinearity

I have explanatory variable age in the model (along with others) and there are several theoretical justification for using square of age variable (along with age) in the model,e,g,[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19823/why-would-one-use-age-squared-as-a-covariate-in-a-genetic-association-study) (if we have a dependent variable income, then this means that income increases as age increases but this increase becomes less as we become older). Now, I checked the correlation between age and age squared and it is more than 95 % (0.987). I think this is not surprising. My question is should we still include age squared along with age as explanatory variables in the model.

Comment: If instead of using $\text{age}^2$ you introduce the functionally equivalent $(\text{age} - \text{mean age})^2,$ what correlation do you find with $\text{age}$? :-)

Comment: It's 0.19. Does this have any relevance?

Comment: Including squares of regressors is a long and common practice, especially in income/labor market econometrics -nowadays most writers do not even feel the need to discuss it in their papers.

Comment: Exactly Alecos. My obsevation is that they even do not discuss the multicollinearity issue associated with its inclusion, which is quite surprising.

Comment: To generalize whuber's excellent suggestion (which indeed does have relevance), orthogonal polynomials are commonly used to deal with the collinearity issue ... by completely removing it.

Comment: Thank you Gen_b. I see the point, but that is not commonly used in the literature.

Comment: Re "the multicollinearity issue": there *is* no multicollinearity when you set up the data correctly (such as by following @Glen_b's suggestion to use an orthogonal polynomial). You saw that when you computed a correlation coefficient of $0.19$: that's practically no correlation at all. To determine whether squared age matters in your model, study the extent to which it helps explain the *response* rather than its relationship to the other explanatory variables. A full explanation appears at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/28493; to apply it here, let $X_1$ be age and $X_2$ be squared age.